# How to run flow with minimal configuration in mosaic

Tags: mosaic-decisions

I'm developing some ETL jobs using Mosaic Decisions. While running the job, it's submitting the job to Spark using the default configurations. This default configuration is really huge and I don't need that much for development (as I am using less number of records for unit testing while development).

Is there a way I can instruct Mosaic to use less Spark resources for my development? So that I won't unnecessarily block the resources of the cluster?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to achieve that. To do so, you will have to create a new **run configuration** with the desired **resource** configuration from the **Manager persona** *(LTI Mosaic Manager)*. Then, simply execute the **flow** with the newly created **run configuration**.

Follow the steps below to create a new run configuration:

1. Log in to `Mosaic Decisions` and on the top right corner, click on Projects, and then on `Manager`.

[image: Mosaic Manager]

2. In `Mosaic Manager`, click on the `Runconfig` tab in the left navigation panel.
3. Click on `Add  New Configuration`. Provide the desired **configurations** and click `Save`.

[image: add new runconfig in Mosaic Manager]

4. Go back to `Mosaic Decisions`, and execute the desired **flow** with the newly created **run configuration**

[image: select created run config while executing flow]